# Remote Desktop Services "Collections" tab is missing on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

We just made the switch to new a server and changed from Windows 2008 R2 to 2012 R2 Datacenter. All the employees connect to this server using Remote Desktop Connection. Everything was going fine until I wanted to try and view someone else's connection.
I remember I used to be able to do this from the Task Manager's "Users" tab but I couldn't find that option in 2012, so I looked online. Apparently you can "shadow" another user's RDP session from the server manager by going to Remote Desktop Services > Collections and going to the Connections section. But for some reason the Collections tab isn't there. I have found I can shadow sessions via the command line using mstsc.exe but I would really like to have a GUI.

Here's a bit more info. I set up this server by installing roles and features using the "Roll-based or feature-based installation" option.
The roles I currently have installed for Remote Desktop Services are:
Remote Desktop Connection Broker
Remote Desktop Gateway
Remote Desktop Licensing
Remote Desktop Session Host

So what do I need to do to get the Collections tab to show up?